# If the Hogwarts kids are invisible, is the Forbidden Forest invisible? Also, what's in it?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

In ***Harry Potter***, we are introduced to the *Forbidden Forest*. We know Harry and his two friends are punished for some reason -- they are told to do something with Hagrid in the Forbidden Forest.

We also know that there are all sorts of creatures in there. But how do we know if they are invisible to the muggles, or if the whole forest is invisible in the first place?

***What is the explanation here?***

Comment: I doubt they're actually invisible.  Probably there's some kind of magic protection set up around the place to deter errant muggles.  Perhaps some kind of magical [S.E.P. Field](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem_field).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harry, Ron, Hermione, and Draco are disciplined by Deputy Headmistress Minerva McGonagall for being out of bed and out and around the castle after curfew. As punishment, the four are sent to track pools of silvery unicorn blood through the Forbidden Forest, looking for dead unicorns. Hagrid is set to supervise the four in the forest while they complete their detention.

In Potterverse, magical creatures are invisible to Muggles.There are a few exceptions. If you count the owls, both Muggles and wizards can see them. In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, there's quite a few instances of a magical creature being seen by a Muggle.

I can't recall reading anywhere that the Forbidden Forest itself is invisible to either wizards or Muggles. The closest I can come is from *Goblet of Fire* -- in it, Hermione explains to Ron and Harry about what Hogwarts looks like to Muggles. Hermione explains that Hogwarts looks like a bunch of broken down ruins with a *Danger! Go Away!* sign in front of it. That would indicate to me that Muggles cannot see the Forbidden Forest.

But that's from the book.

I can't recall an instance in any of the *Harry Potter* movies where the Forbidden Forest is invisible to either Muggles or wizards. I do not believe it is invisible in the movies. What is *inside* the forest, however, likely varies -- Muggles probably cannot see the creatures inside; wizards probably can.

Comment: There's no reason there the ruins that Muggles see in place of Hogwarts can't have a creepy looking forest next to it. There are probably spells that ensure that Muggles stay away from it.

Comment: @Llewellyn - No, there's no reason why there couldn't be a forest next to the ruins. Hermione describes it as "mouldering ruins" and suggests there are spells hiding Hogwarts and making it unplottable. But, yeah, sure, no reason why the ruins couldn't border the Forbidden Forest. :)